# D3D11_USAGE_STAGING, what kind of GPU/CPU memory is used?

Tags: windows, directx, gpu, directx-11

I read the [D3D11 Usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476259(v=vs.85).aspx) page and coming from a CUDA background I'm wondering what kind of memory would a texture marked as `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` be stored into.

I suppose in CUDA it would be pinned page-locked zero-copy memory. I measured the transfer time from a `ID3D11Texture2D` with `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` to a host buffer allocated with `malloc` and it took almost 7 milliseconds (quite a lot in streaming/gaming) and I thought this would be the time required from GPU global memory to that memory area.

Is any of my suppositions correct? What is `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` using as GPU memory?

Comment: How did you measure the time? From the map to copy complete? Or just the copy? (Worth ruling out any timing issues related to waiting for the GPU to finish with the resource, etc).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The primary use for `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` is as a way to load data into other `D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT` pool resources. Another common usage is for 'readback' of a render target to CPU accessible memory. You can use `CopySubResourceRegion` to move data between DEFAULT and STAGING resources (discrete hardware often uses [Direct Memory Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) to handle the moving of data between system memory and VRAM).

This is a generalization because it depends on the architecture and driver choices, but in short::

- `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` means put it in system memory, and the GPU can't access it.
- `D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT` put it in the VRAM, the CPU can't access it. To put data into it requires copying data from a STAGING resource.  You can think of `UpdateSubresource` as a convenience function that creates a STAGING resource, copies the data to it, copies from STAGING to DEFAULT, then releases the STAGING copy.

  - There is an optional feature in DirectX 11.2 or later than can be implemented by the driver if they choose to allow CPU access even to `D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT` pool stuff. This depends on how they have their memory system setup (i.e. in [Unified Memory Architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit#Integrated_graphics), system RAM and VRAM are the same thing).
- `D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE` is basically the same as `D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT`, but you are saying you are only going to initialize it once in the creation call.
- `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` means put it in shared system memory, the CPU & GPU both need access to it. There's usually a performance hit for the GPU to read from this compared to DEFAULT, so you want to use it sparingly. It's really for stuff you generate every frame on the CPU and then need to render (such as terrain systems or procedural geometry).

> Games that use content streaming typically have a set of STAGING textures they load data into in the background, and then copy it to `DEFAULT` textures as they become available for efficient rendering. This lets them reuse both STAGING and DEFAULT textures without the overhead of destroying/creating resources every frame.

See this somewhat dated article on Microsoft Docs: [Resource Management Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/resource-management-best-practices)

Comment: Could you elaborate on async staging copy? Loading on the background would still require a Map on DeviceContext (which is not thread safe), from what I read elsewhere games tend to use Initial Data on resource creation instead?

Comment: You can still share a device context on multiple threads if you deal with synchronization directly, so some streaming games will do the load, submit to a work queue for the mapping, etc. InitData is definitely another approach, although it requires creating and destroying resources which is a potential performance impact.